# error when publishing website on Virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, azure, virtual-machine

I'm trying to publish my website on a virtual machine. I need to use the virtual machine because the website uses an .exe file and I needed somewhere to host it and a machine to run it. I spent days trying to connect my website to a database, and now it finally works. But it works from my local machine. When I publish it on my VM, it gives me this error:

> AADSTS50011: The redirect URI
> 'http://arinleviti.italynorth.cloudapp.azure.com/signin-oidc'
> specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured
> for the application '6cd54832-d1e0-4612-9a74-c441dfeaef4c'.

I tried to include that string in app registration under Redirect URIs, but it won't accept http, only https, so now I'm stuck. Can I configure Visual Studio to create a https version of that string and deploy it? I'm not even sure why we need a login, when i publish my website on a virtual machine i want it to be accessible to everyone. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to add `https` in RedirectURI. `http` is allowed only for `localhost` not for the deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Harshitha, According to this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reply-url#supported-schemes) and this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952152/setting-up-redirect-uri-for-azure-ad-authentication-from-native-app) by Tony Ju

> - Redirect URIs must begin with the scheme  `https`. There are some  [exceptions for localhost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reply-url#localhost-exceptions) redirect URIs.
> - **HTTPS**: The HTTPS scheme (`https://`) is supported for all HTTP-based redirect URIs.
> - **HTTP**: The HTTP scheme (`http://`) is supported  *only*  for  *localhost*  URIs and should be used only during active local application development and testing.

***I tried adding the https based uri via App manifest editor and Authentication section in Azure Portal but it failed:-***

[image]

[image]

In your ***Cloud services Extended Support*** you need to add **`SSL Certificate`** and enable **`https://`** for your Cloud service URL deployed in the VM.

***In order to enable SSL Certificate.***

1. Edit your **`csdef file`** and add the **`Webrole`** for your certificate:-

> ```xml
>   </WebRole> <WebRole name="CertificateTesting" vmsize="Small">
>     <Certificates>
>         <Certificate name="SampleCertificate"
>                     storeLocation="LocalMachine"
>                     storeName="My"
>                     permissionLevel="limitedOrElevated" />
>         <!-- IMPORTANT! Unless your certificate is either
>         self-signed or signed directly by the CA root, you
>         must include all the intermediate certificates
>         here. You must list them here, even if they are
>         not bound to any endpoints. Failing to list any of
>         the intermediate certificates may cause hard-to-reproduce
>         interoperability problems on some clients.-->
>         <Certificate name="CAForSampleCertificate"
>                     storeLocation="LocalMachine"
>                     storeName="CA"
>                     permissionLevel="limitedOrElevated" />
>     </Certificates> </WebRole> <WebRole name="CertificateTesting" vmsize="Small">
>     <Endpoints>
>         <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443"
>             certificate="CertificateSid" />
>     </Endpoints> </WebRole> <WebRole name="CertificateTesting" vmsize="Small">
>     <Sites>
>         <Site name="Web">
>             <Bindings>
>                 <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
>             </Bindings>
>         </Site>
>     </Sites> </WebRole>
> ```

And in your service configuration file **.cscfg** add the certificate value:-

```xml
<Role name="Deployment">
    <Certificates>
        <Certificate name="CertificateSid"
            thumbprint="ehemdnd63637ndnfnf939304odncn316ff"
            thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
        <Certificate name="CAForSampleCertificate"
            thumbprint="sjedjei3o45464848ec6865a9ebdc"
            thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
</Role>
```

Refer [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal) for detailed steps.

Now, Add the **.csdef file** and **.cscfg file** as a deployment  like below:-

[image]

In your ***Cloud Services (Classic)*** just add **cspkg** and **cscfg file** with your certificate:-

[image]

[image]